# Move rows to column and columns to row in oralce SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I am getting the following oracle SQL output from my script.

```
Status     Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
Processed     22    12    10     0
Error         11    22     0     0
Unsent        10    11     0    22
```

I would like to move the rows to column and columns to row and display as following format in SQL using PIVOT & UNPIVOT.

```
Items   Processed  Error  Unsent
Item1          22     11      10
Item2          12     22      11 
Item3          10      0       0
Item4           0      0      22
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky; it requires an unpivot and pivot.  Here is one method:

```
select item,
       sum(case when status = 'Processed' then val end) as processed,
       sum(case when status = 'Error' then val end) as error,
       sum(case when status = 'Unsent' then val end) as unsent
from ((select 'Item1' as item, status, item1 as val from t
      ) union all
      (select 'Item2' as item, status, item2 from t
      ) union all
      (select 'Item3' as item, status, item3 from t
      ) 
     ) i
group by item;
```

Comment: @Gordan Linoff, Thank you for quick answer. Do you know how to do this using unpivot & pivot?

Comment: There is an excellent blog by Chris Saxon on this topic. https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using conditional aggregation including `unpivot` expression :

```
select items as "Items",
       max(case when status = 'Processed' then value end) as "Processed",
       max(case when status = 'Error' then value end) as "Error",
       max(case when status = 'Unsent' then value end) as "Unsent"
  from tab
unpivot (value for items in ( Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4 ))
  group by items
  order by "Items";
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8baa49cb8b0a025c49c0499aa57d86b7)</kbd>

to unpivot the data firstly, and then tidy them up pivoted by conditional aggregation.